# Change Live Charts circles size

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I want change size of all legend and tooltip circles in Live Charts.
I searched all documentation but I don't know how it is called. How to change size of every circle in tooltip and legend?

```
PieChart pieChart = new PieChart();
pieChart.Width = 400;
pieChart.Height = 300;

pieChart.LegendLocation = LegendLocation.Bottom;

PieSeries pieSeries = new PieSeries();
pieSeries.Values = new ChartValues<int> { 5 };
pieSeries.Title = "A";
pieSeries.DataLabels = true;

PieSeries pieSeries2 = new PieSeries();
pieSeries2.Values = new ChartValues<int> { 3 };
pieSeries2.Title = "B";
pieSeries2.DataLabels = true;

PieSeries pieSeries3 = new PieSeries();
pieSeries3.Values = new ChartValues<int> { 6 };
pieSeries3.Title = "C";
pieSeries3.DataLabels = true;

pieChart.Series.Add(pieSeries);
pieChart.Series.Add(pieSeries2);
pieChart.Series.Add(pieSeries3);
```

[image: Live Charts circle]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it:
Programmatically:

```
PieChart pieChart = new PieChart();
((DefaultLegend)pieChart.ChartLegend).BulletSize = 50;
((DefaultTooltip)pieChart.DataTooltip).BulletSize = 50;
```

XAML:

```
<lvc:PieChart Name="myPieChart" Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}">
    <lvc:PieChart.ChartLegend>
        <lvc:DefaultLegend BulletSize="20"></lvc:DefaultLegend>
    </lvc:PieChart.ChartLegend>
    <lvc:PieChart.DataTooltip>
        <lvc:DefaultTooltip BulletSize="20"></lvc:DefaultTooltip>
    </lvc:PieChart.DataTooltip>
</lvc:PieChart>
```